# Ajax data is not posting in windows server and xampserver(localhost)

Tags: php, html, ajax, post

I am trying to send data using Ajax Post method, but it is not functioning in windows server(plesk), and xampserver. Below is the ajax code. But it is functioning properly with other servers.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#checkbox').click(function() {
        $.ajax({type : "POST",
            url : "test.php",
            data : "ffs=some data&ffs2=somedata2",
            success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
        Check box : <input type = "checkbox" name = "checkbox" id = "checkbox">
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats unfortunate. Are you getting any errors. Have you looked for errors

Comment: What about it is not functioning? Check the network tab in your web browser, is the request being sent? What does your PHP output as a response? Check https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings, you're using jQuery version 1.11.1

Comment: Try changing the `data` and pass values as an object like `data: {ffs: var1, ffs2: var2}` put the values into these var1 and var2 variable. Hope this will solve the problem

Comment: can you see any error in the console while try to run AJAX?

Comment: I made changes to the code as @HJ Noyon Suggests and it is as following.

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var var1="test1";
  var var2="test2";
        $('#checkbox').click(function() {
        $.ajax({type : "POST",
            url : "test.php",
  data : "{ffs: var1, ff2: var2}",
            success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        });
    });
</script>

But still not working. Thaks lot for ur time.

Comment: Data is sending properly when i check network tab @Profit

Comment: it returns simply 'Hi..' which is echoed in test.php

Following is the code in test.php

echo 'Hi..'.$_POST['ffs'];

But i only gets "Hi.." the other part is empty, which means ajax post doesnt functioning. Right?

Comment: can you show your php code. If you only echo 'hi..' then you will only get 'hi..' . To get any data back by ajax request you need to echo it from your php code. Ajax is functioning, there is no issue with it.